Liferay 7 Cluster Configuration
I try to setup a Liferay 7.4 CE cluster env from this overview: link
I wish to use DBStore for DL in the File Store Cluster.
My question is: how to enable DBStore for a clustered env in CE successfully? I tried this: link
but the configuration section doesn´t appear in the control panel after the restart.
Can anyone help here?
Thanks and regards,
Christian

As this is not programming-related: Consider bringing it over to the Liferay Community (e.g. https://liferay.dev) where it would be on-topic.
